# Why would an employer prevent their employees from investing in the employer's stock through the employer-sponsored 401(k) account?

Tags: united-states, 401k, employer

Why would an employer prevent their employees from investing in the employer's stock through the employer-sponsored 401(k) account? I saw that restriction when reading the "Vanguard Brokerage Option (VBO)® Plan Highlights" of a 401(k) Vanguard account sponsored by some US company.

Note: the Self-Directed Brokerage Option (SDBO) previously known as the 
Vanguard Brokerage Option (VBO).

Comment: Too much concentration of risk: it's bad enough that your income is tied to the success of one company, but if your retirement savings are also?!?

Comment: Is this an actual situation or just a hypothetical? There are many reasons why you might not _want_ to invest in your companies stock, but some companies allow (and even _encourage_ it, so I'm not sure what answer you're looking for here.

Comment: @DStanley Actual situation. I was wondering whether it is the employer's decision not to allow employees to directly purchase the employer's stock in their 401(k)s or some external factors (e.g.,  laws) explain such restrictions. And if it is the employer's decision, are they trying to protect the employees (e.g., not enough diverse investments or insider trading) or themselves (I don't see what but I may be missing something).

Comment: Is the 401(k) one of those that lets you invest in whatever stocks you want by a brokerage window? Otherwise, if the 401(k) plan doesn't offer an option of company stock, then you can't buy it, the same way you can't buy any of the tens of thousands of investments available, you can only buy the 10 to 100 or so choices they give you.

Comment: @stannius this 401(k) allows to invest in any stock except the employer's stock.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I found this document on SEC requirements for employers who do allow purchase of company stock through a brokerage window. https://benefitsbclp.com/sec-guidance-on-registration-of-401k-plan-interests-when-brokerage-windows-are-offered/ It seems that it is probably OK as long as they don't mention the possibility. I can certainly imagine some companies choosing to simply prohibit such purchases, out of an abundance of caution, or because  they wrote their plan rules before the guidance was issued.

Comment: @stannius  Thanks for the information. Good to know that's the employer's decision not to allow employees to directly purchase the employer's stock in their 401(k)s. You're welcome to add it as an additional answer. (I'm always afraid that useful comments get deleted)

Comment: I have no idea but I suspect the company may also have an ESPP in place

Comment: @quid They do. Aside from reinforcing the concentration of risk, does that change something?

Comment: I'm just speculating here but, I'd say that since the employees had the ESPP available to them to buy the stock at a discount the employer might be open to some liability if a begrudged employee were to buy stock via the 401(k) that the employer should have done a better job directing employees to the ESPP instead because the employee would have gotten a better deal.  The easy solution to avoid that liability would be to disallow purchase of the stock in the K.

Comment: And for whatever it'd worth I disagree almost completely with what's been said here about never investing in the company you work for.  No one should ever be 100% invested in any single entity whether or not they work there but that doesn't mean you should never have exposure to the performance of the company you work for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a document on [SEC requirements for employers who do allow purchase of company stock through a brokerage window](https://benefitsbclp.com/sec-guidance-on-registration-of-401k-plan-interests-when-brokerage-windows-are-offered/) ([mirror](http://archive.is/j1OjC)). I am extrapolating heavily from a document covering only a specific case, but it seems that there is more paperwork and more risk of an employer being sued if they offer employer stock through their 401(k) program. According to that document, the mere availability of employer stock through a brokerage window doesn't require paperwork or introduce risks, with the caveat that they can't point it out (and definitely can't recommend, encourage, or endorse it to employees). I can certainly imagine some companies choosing to simply prohibit such purchases, either out of an abundance of caution, or because they wrote their plan rules before the guidance was issued.

Answer (score 6):

Because it's a super-bad terrible no-good diversification fail ...that also makes the company *all too* responsible for the employee's fate after retirement.

That is, after all, exactly how things worked in the Bad Old Days.  You get home after V-J day and go to work for the Baldwin  Locomotive Works, a stalwart blue-chip who had been in business for 120 years making steam locomotives (uh-oh).  Your service will earn you a pension, which  BLW pays out of profits just as it did for your grandfather and great grandfather. However, this ever-growing pension burden meant that BLW was becoming a pension company that happened to make locomotives on the side.

Well, fortunately, the pension industry had become savvy to this dangerous practice, and had changed the corporate structure so BLW  was paying into a pension *fund*.  The fund was separate, and wouldn't go bankrupt if BLW did.  Except the two Boards of Directors were the same people.  When BLW needed a loan, they borrowed from the pension fund.  If they didn't have cash to pay into the pension fund, they issued it stock.  So employee pensions were heavily invested in stock of, or loans to, the employer.

This resulted in a great many employees having their pensions go bust and become a burden to the government.  This was landing in the government's lap to such an extreme degree that the government just "made it official", and formed the Social Security system.   Later, the concept of a 401K was developed, so employees could direct their own retirement savings instead of fund managers.

However, the idea of investing your retirement *in your own company* has basically become a four letter word.  Retirement should be invested in things that are *safe as houses*, and the financial industry already knows what that is, because university endowments are invested there.  That is: a very broad mix of stocks, foreign stocks, bonds, insured investments, cashlikes, and sometimes a small fraction of real estate. And as the withdrawal time of the investment approaches, slowly roll the asset mix out of stocks and more into cashlikes.

But not just any stocks - the most diverse selection possible, so that no one failure of a business or sector can significantly damage the fund.

The problem with *allowing* employees to invest retirement in their own company is that companies will be tempted to *oblige* them to.   For instance, my company puts my investments into a Target Fund by default, and I have to log in and positively move it.  Imagine of they put it in their company's stock by default?  For many employees, it would not even occur to them to change the investment mix to something sane.  They would move on to other jobs, then at retirement find their retirement fund was extinguished because all the stock in it went to 0.   That would drag us right back to the Bad Old Days.

Comment: Thanks. "The problem with allowing employees to invest retirement in their own company is that companies will be tempted to oblige them to" -> do you mean employers are not allowed to allow employees to invest retirement in their own company?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I don't know enough about pension law to say definitely, but *it wouldn't surprise me one bit*.  Regardless, it would require the cooperation of the 401k manager (e.g. Vanguard or Fidelity) and *I think it would be difficult finding one who'd agree to it* for ethical (the above) reasons, and fear of liability or conflict of interest for recommending such a fund if it tanks.

Comment: @Harper I work in the US and Fidelity manages our 401(k). They have a special mutual fund holding company stock, which is only available to employee 401(k) accounts. So we are allowed to invest our 401(k) in company stock, AND the entire employer match is in company stock. If Fidelity does it I'm sure it's legal.

Comment: @Pacman Thanks for the information. Good to know that's the employer's decision not to allow employees to directly purchase the employer's  stock in their 401(k)s. You're welcome to add it as an additional answer. (I'm always afraid that useful comments get deleted)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the board of directors wanted to have the ability to have more control over the company. Within my 401k I can not buy any more co. Stock after doing so after 20 years. I can move my shares out but can not buy them back. If the Board  Was to trying to get you to diversify, why not limit the amount of shares you can own.

Also, no one can buy any shares in the future in the 401k
Is the board of directors trying to increase control
over the co.  Trying to get more control over the co.